# JavaScript condition for operations not working as required

Tags: javascript

I want to check some operator condition and based on that I will assign some values. So below is my condition.

```
if (checkIfUserRequesterApprover == "VSAT Approver" && IsDraftOrSave == "Save" || IsDraftOrSave == "Draft") {
    VSATSaving.IS_SUBMIT = 0;
    VSATSaving.STATUS_ID = 1;
}
```

and in my `checkIfUserRequesterApprover` is `VSAT Requester`

> still both the conditions are satisfying and going inside. HOW is that possible ?

Comment: I think you need `(checkIfUserRequesterApprover == "VSAT Approver" && (IsDraftOrSave == "Save" || IsDraftOrSave == "Draft"))` Since _Logical AND_ has higher precedence over _Logical OR_

Comment: i think , you may use barckets after && condition

Comment: @Satpal: let me try with this

Comment: @Satpal: thanks satpal, its working. dont know why. but was confused

Comment: @VVVV it's due to precedence rule . that's why your condition was not working properly .

Comment: @vjytiwari: yes. thanks a lot to all for suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like your if expression should be 
`(checkIfUserRequesterApprover == "VSAT Approver" && (IsDraftOrSave == "Save" || IsDraftOrSave == "Draft"))`

Comment: thanks beni, accepting your answer but the original one I got it from Satpal.. :)

Comment: sorry, I didn't saw his comment on your question.. we answered you at the same minute or so

Comment: not an issue for me.. u both guys were helpful. anyways thanks

Comment: great, glad we could help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add brackets to group the expressions in the condition.

When you write :

```
 if (checkIfUserRequesterApprover == "VSAT Approver" && IsDraftOrSave == "Save" || IsDraftOrSave == "Draft")
```

and your checkIfUserRequesterApprover is 'VSAT Requester', it returns false.
Since Java starts evaluating the expression from left hand side and your first expression is false followed by && second expression, so first two expression will always evaluate to false, which will be followed by || and third expression, this will make your result dependent on third expression.
(false && false || false) = (false || false) = false
(false && false|| true) = (false || true) = true
(false && true || false) = (false || false) = false
(false && true|| true) = (false || true) = true

Answer (score -2):

Use brackets to combine conditions properly.